# How to insert an if condition in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to do a for loop and explain it here by simple print function. I want  change the data printed after a fixed value. Let's regard this code:

```
for i in range (7):
    print (i, i+15, i+1)
```

it gives me:

```
0 15 1
1 16 2
2 17 3
3 18 4
4 19 5
5 20 6
6 21 7
```

But I want to add `1` to the printed values of the second row after each `3` interation. I mean from the first to third iteration, I want the same results as printed above. But from third to sixth I want to add `1` to `i+15` (printing `i+16` rather than `i+15`). Then again after the sixth row, I want to add `1` to `i+16` (printing `i+17` rather than `i+16` or `i+15`). I mean I want to have this one:

```
0 15 1
1 16 2
2 17 3
3 19 4
4 20 5
5 21 6
6 23 7
```

How can I make my `i` in the function to e such a thing? Itried the following but it gives another thing:

```
for i in range (7):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print (i, i+15+1, i+1)
    else:
        print (i, i+15, i+1)
```

I do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: `print(i, i + 15 + i // 3)` - is this what you are looking for? No `if`s needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range (7):
    print (i, i//3+i+15, i+1)

0 15 1
1 16 2
2 17 3
3 19 4
4 20 5
5 21 6
6 23 7
```

For ranges that don't start from 0, to keep the same logic (increment every 3 iterations) you can do the following:

```
for i in range (4,15):
        print (i, (i-4)//3+i+15, i+1)

4 19 5
5 20 6
6 21 7
7 23 8
8 24 9
9 25 10
10 27 11
11 28 12
12 29 13
13 31 14
14 32 15
```

Comment: Dear @IoaTzimas Thanks for you helpful solution. I tried to do it for ranges which does not start from 0, but it does not work out for them. Can you please tell me how I can extend your solution to other ranges (for example `range (4, 10)`)? I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure, do you want to always keep groups of 3, no matter the start of the range?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My steps are 3 but start is from 4 up tp 10 (for example). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code updated. Just add (i-k)//3 where k is the start of the range

Answer (score 2):

```
print("Hello world")
starting = 14;
for i in range (7):
    
    if(i %3==0):
        starting=starting+1
    print (i, i+starting, i+1)
```

Just added if condition to detect

Answer (score 1):

You can do smth like this:

```
for i in range(7):
    print(i, i + 15 + i // 3, i + 1)
```

or, if you want, you can save this delta to variable.

```
inc = 0
for i in range(7):
    if i > 0 and i % 3 == 0:
        inc += 1
    print(i, i + 15 + inc, i + 1)
```

I think more pythonic way of 2nd variant:

```
inc = 0
for i in range(7):
    if i > 0:
        inc += i % 3 == 0
    print(i, i + 15 + inc, i + 1)
```